# javascript text field value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate even and odd numbers through a text field,the text field is the range where I put values ,and I select even and odd through select tag.So how am I supposed to get the value from text field to calculate function?

**JavaScript Code**

```
 function calculate()
 { 
 var i=0; for(i=1;i<=1000;i++) 
  { 
   if(i%2==0) { 
 document.getElementById("even").value="the numbers is" + i + "<br>";
  } 
else {
document.getElementById("odd").value="the numbers is" + i + "<br>"; }
} 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body> 
<input type="text" name="value" value="" id="value1" placeholder="Enter the 
first number" /> 
<select> 
   <option value="even" id="even">Even</option> 
   <option value="odd" id="odd">Odd</option>
   </select>
 <p id="value1"> </p> 
<p id="even"> </p>
 <p id="odd"> </p>
 <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
```

Comment: please share your html,javascript code and above all what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried till now ?

Comment: Use a reference to your text field using DOM selector and use `.value` function

Comment: script>
     function calculate()  { var i=0;
     for(i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
     if(i%2==0) {
      document.getElementById("even").value="the numbers is" + i + "<br>";
      } else {
      document.getElementById("odd").value="the numbers is" + i + "<br>";
}
}
}
</script> </head>

Comment: <body>
<input type="text" name="value" value="" id="value1" placeholder="Enter the first number"  />
<select>
<option value="even" id="even">Even</option>
<option value="odd" id="odd">Odd</option>
</select>
<p id="value1"> </p>
<p id="even"> </p>
 <p id="odd"> </p>
 <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />

Comment: please put your html code in your question. so we can get a better idea

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this page [Input Text value Property - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

To get value from input field you can use :

```
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
```

To set value in input field you can use :

```
document.getElementById("myText").value = "my value";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setters:**

```
document.getElementById("yourInputField").value = "Value";  // JavaScript
$('#yourInputField').val(Value);  // jQuery
```

**Getters:**

```
var Value = document.getElementById("yourInputField").value;  // JavaScript
var Value = $('#yourInputField').val();  // jQuery
```

Use them in your calculation method, and enjoy. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand you need to pick value of your text box but you will also need a function that gets hit on key press and passes your textbox value to **calculate()** function

use this function that will get executed once you press a key.

```
$("#yourtextboxidhere").keyup(function(){

        var textValue =  $.trim( $('#yourtextboxidhere').val() ); 

        // convert the string value from text box to int so you can use it in your calculate function for comparison 
        // as text box values are string)
        var textValue = parseInt(textValue)



    //Put your calculate function here and pass it the value:
    calculate(textValue);

    //calculate function goes here.... (don't forget to add a parameter in you calculate function so you may use it in a correct way)

//replace 'i' in your function with the passed parameter.


    });
```

don't forget to use jquery.